# JAX-RS not returning exception when using RESPONSE as a return type

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Is it in some way possible that an exception thrown from a rest service is returned as JSON? I have a JAX-RS Rest Service where I would like to achieve this. Basically, I am returning a zip file as a Response from our API which is working as expected but when I am getting any exception the same I want to return it as a JSON response from API. Is there any way to achieve this:

```
    @RolesAllowed({"admin", "analyst", "investigator", "supervisor", "data_scientist", "quality_assurance", "executive", "confidential"})
@Path("/download/{id}")
@GET
@Produces("application/zip")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns a List.", notes = "")
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "", response = VO.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "", response = ErrorMessage.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "", response = ErrorMessage.class) })
public Response downloadFile(
        @HeaderParam("x-access-token") String jwtToken, 
        @Context SecurityContext sec,
        @Context final HttpServletResponse response, 
        @PathParam("id") String id)
         throws Exception {

    ErrorMessage errorMessage=new ErrorMessage();
    ResponseBuilder response1=null;
    try{
 
    if (id == null) {
        throw new BusinessException("Id should not be empty.Please provide Id.");
    }

    String File=DownloadUtil.exportToFile(wl);

    byte[] bytes =Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(File));

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream( out );
    zipOut.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( File ) );
    
    zipOut.write(bytes);

    zipOut.closeEntry();
    zipOut.close();

    response1 = Response.ok(out.toByteArray());
    response1.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=list.zip");
    }
      catch (Exception msg) 
    {
       
       errorMessage.setCode(422);//your custom error code
       errorMessage.setMessage("Error occured");//custom status
       
       return Response.status(200).entity(errorMessage).build();
   }
    return response1.build();
}
```

Using the above error message technique I am getting the following exception and in the response getting [Object Blob]:

```
No message body writer has been found for class com.test.exception.ErrorMessage, ContentType: application/zip
```

Comment: You can set the media type to JSON by calling `type(..)` after calling `entity(..)` on the ResponseBuilder

Comment: @PaulSamsotha: As you suggested I did the changes i.e after entity added type("JSON") or .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON). but getting the following issue "[ERROR   ] No message body writer has been found for class com.test.exception.ErrorMessage, ContentType: */*.   "

Comment: Why does it say / for the content-type in the error message?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha:: It is  **/* * in the error message.

Comment: My question is _why_? That's what you need to figure out. It means that is what you are setting the media type to.

Comment: When i am setting it like this "return Response.status(200).entity(errorMessage).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();" it is not returning any response i.e it running infinitely and i was not getting the error i got for type(JSON)

Comment: Are you able to return the ErrorMessage response in JSON in any other case besides this one?

Comment: If I replaced the @Produces("application/zip") with @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) then I am getting the error message as JSON but in that case, I am not getting the success scenario i.e when no error occurs i should have a zip file as a response

Comment: Try to remove the `@Produces` and set the type manually in both cases. Or maybe try to set both `@Produces({"application/json", "application/zip"})`

Comment: With @Produces({"application/json", "application/zip"}) --> Getting the same issue with zip mediaType i.e not getting any response.
When manually added 
       return return response.status(200).entity(errorMessage).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build(); 
    return response.type("ZIP").build();
getting both the responses but when unzipping the file getting inappropriate file format error.

Comment: Try to throw a WebApplicationException and pass the ErrorMessage Response to its constructor. Leave the Produces as zip but set the type in the error response.